# Undoing a Mercurial push

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using [TortoiseHg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseHg) for version control. I pushed to the remote repository after commiting to the local. How do I undo to a particular commit point?

There were three distinct pushes, and I want to revert to the first push. I read about the **hg rollback** and **hg undo** commands, but I am not sure how to use them to accomplish this.

Comment: Hay is the long grass that has been cut and dried, used as food for cattle. :-)

Comment: Besides this article is useful "[Finding And Fixing Mistakes](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html)".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you have pushed to another repository, you have no way of knowing where your changes have propagated to. If you hadn't pushed, you could do undo, but undo only does the last transaction anyway.

The other option to truly modify history would be the strip command, but again, because you've pushed, this is not an option. If you stripped your local, you'd still get the changesets back the next time you pulled.

If you have access to the central, you could strip it, but if someone else has already pulled your changes, then they would re-appear in the central again the next time they push.

Your only safe option at this point in time is the backout command. This basically creates a new changeset at tip that reverses the changesets you've accidentally put in.

Answer (score 14):

From a "puristic" Mercurial perspective, Mike is right - pushed changesets are out of your control. **But**, in practice this is often a too strict perspective.

In opposition to what Mike said, stripping already pushed changesets **may** be an option. It depends on whether you have control over the central repository (to strip there too) and on the size of your team/community and how it is organized.

If you know for sure nobody has pulled your bad changesets yet, just strip your local and the central repo - done, history deleted.

If there is a chance someone pulled your bad changesets already, you'd have strip the local and central repo as well **and** you'd have to notify all pushing team members to strip the bad changesets in their local repos too (or to reclone from the stripped central repo). If you're lucky, everyone does what you say. Otherwise the changesets end up in the central repo again, sooner or later.

The bottom line is that stripping might be a solution for cases like your's - you have to balance the cost (burden your team with extra work) and the benefit (clean history).

---

A practical example where the benefit outweighs the cost would be if you've accidentally added large binary files. In that case probably every team member prefers to strip synchronously instead of working with a blown up repository.

---

**UPDATE:** You can use server side hooks to prevent stripped changesets from getting back into the central repository - [read more here](http://ry4an.org/unblog/post/mercurial_changeset_blacklist/).

Comment: You are right, I took a very 'puristic' stance on this one. It is possible to clean up, and your example is a great one where you'd definitely want to invest the effort, and followup, required.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [hginit.com's 'fixing goofs' page](http://hginit.com/03.html). You want to "back out", merge, and push. What this actually does is create a new commit that performs the inverse of the changes, and applies it.